# Multiple executors on same worker spark standalone

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I was reading that there should be the possibility to run multiple executors on a worker instance on spark-standalone.

https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/731

But it looks like it is not merged, yet.
Anyone can confirm?
In case to speed up processing I can still use more executors setting:

> spark_worker_instances

Is that all I need to do?

Comment: It's been merged for a long time: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-1706

Comment: So what would be the configuration to set up ?